# IOS know when NSTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath is done if it scrolled or not

Tags: ios, nstableview

Need to know when scrollToRowAtIndexPath is done if it scrolled or not.

Can't use the scroll routines because of the case when the row is already in place and the table does not scroll.

Would not like to use some timer / invalidation to do this if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that had to use an NSTimer, etc.  Here is how it goes...  If someone has a better way...

```
In routine that tells the indexPath to scroll to
 Scroll to IndexPath
 tableMoving = true
 set NSTimer to fire MovingDone at 0.1

In scrollViewDidScroll
 if tableMoving
   invalidate timer
   timer = nil

In scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation
 if tableMoving
    call MovingDone

In MovingDone
 moving = false
 // do end of table scrolling code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath...`, do this:

```
BOOL visible = NO;
for (UITableViewCell *cell in [tableView visibleCells])
    if ([indexPath isEqual:[tableView indexPathForCell:cell]]) {
        visible = YES;
        break
    }
```

If you need to, store visible as a member variable of your view controller so you can check its value when you handle some delegate method.

Comment: Um, does not answer question.  The table could still be scrolling up.  Also break is a goto.  Also, want async way to be notified.